# Installing Bash on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-10-v1607, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have got the Anniversary Update for Windows 10 and would now like to install bash (I know some basic functions of bash). However, I do not feel comfortable enabling 'developer mode' in order to install bash.

I have already looked at this post: [Is Windows 10's "enable developer mode" dangerous?](https://superuser.com/questions/1108356/is-windows-10s-enable-developer-mode-dangerous) but this post is way hard for me to understand.

I would like to install bash in windows BUT without enabling developer mode. E.g. is it possible to disable developer mode after installing bash?

I am a beginner with computers so if you think that it is safe to enable developer mode, then please explain why do you think so.
Otherwise PLEASE let me know how to install bash without enabling developer mode.

I have used puTTy but would prefer installing bash on window.

Please share your thoughts. Much appreciated.

Comment: How do you install Bash? Through Cygwin?

Comment: You can't enable this new feature without enabling developer mode at this time.  What you want isn't possible.  Just don't load anything you don't trust....

Comment: [run bash on win10](https://superuser.com/a/1217889/623314)

Comment: This video shows a complete tutorial: https://youtu.be/QukZ7wJNvro and https://youtu.be/4lA6Qs2firA . It will help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution will be to enable the developer mode and install bash.

You should be fine as long as you don't install any software(.exe/.msi)/modern apps(.appx files) from unknown sources. The developer mode allows you to do that. Install modern apps only from Windows store and you will be fine. Don't install any pirate or unknown software.

---

Bash cannot be installed without enabling developer mode. Bash for Windows 10 is introduced for development purposes. So it will be that way. Also developer mode needs to be enabled in order for Bash to work.

---

**Steps to Install bash:**

You can take a look at [this article](https://mspoweruser.com/install-bash-windows-10/) for detailed steps:

1. Enable developer mode.
2. Search and open Windows Features.
3. Check Windows Subsystem for Linux (Beta) and apply the changes.
4. Open command prompt and type bash and hit Enter.
5. When asked for conformation press 'y' and hit Enter.

---

### Warning

If you are so afraid of using developer features or doubt of breaking your system, **Don't use them**. Note that Bash feature is also in beta.